# Extracting min-length and max-length element from list

Tags: python

Let's say I have two parameters `a` and `b` and I want to assign the smaller and bigger (by length, if they are the same length I don't care which one) to respective variables. Either case like

- `a == b`
- `len(a) == len(b)` but `a != b`

results in a (to my knowledge) non-straightforward solution:

```
def compare(a, b):
    smallest = min([a, b], key=len)
    temp = [a, b]
    temp.remove(smallest) # Why does this return void?
    biggest = temp[0]

    do_something(smallest, biggest)
```

Is there an easier/shorter way?

Example input would be `foo` and `bar` or `hello` and `hello`.

```
>>>smallest, biggest = min(["foo", "bar"], key=len), max(["foo", "bar"], key=len)
('foo', 'foo')
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: why not use min and max? what is value range of foo and bar.

Comment: `smallest, biggest = sorted([a, b], key=len)`??

Comment: @Rawing, damn, that's too easy. Thanks :) Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the two values in a list, sort it, then unpack it into two variables:

```
smallest, biggest = sorted([a, b], key=len)
```